Correlated random effects: mixed effects as a factor model
I am trying to build a fundamental factor model in the style of Fama-French. I have the FF factors as well as the industries in which my assets belong.
The model is specified as:
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + \mathbf{Z}\gamma + \epsilon 
$$
where, $\mathbf{Y}$ is a cross-sectional time-series matrix of $N$ assets and $T$ weekly returns; $\mathbf{X}$ are the Fama-French factors (weekly returns of the HML, SMB, WML and Market-RF portfolios); $\mathbf{Z}$ is a matrix of random effects. I have a simple case whereby there are only random intercepts and no random slopes, i.e., $\mathbf{Z}$ is a matrix of 1s and 0s indicating the industry in which the asset belongs. $\epsilon$ are the residuals which are distributed $N(0,1)$, $\gamma$ are the random intercepts $N(0,\mathbf{G})$ and $\beta$ are the usual, fixed slopes (and one fixed intercept) in this case.
We can fit this model using statsmodels' mixed linear model.
The dataframe looks like this:

We fit the model by simply:
md = smf.mixedlm("y ~ MktRF + SMB + HML + WML", X,  groups=X["sector"])
res = md.fit()

The results are horrible, however. There is almost a perfect linear relationship between the residuals and the fitted values.

My suspicion is that something is off with the covariance matrix, $\mathbf{G}$ since this is close to singular. One of the common approaches I read about regarding this issue is that the random effects might be overparametrized and that multicollinearity might be present there. Hence, I computed (with some padding out of neccessity) the correlations between the industries - our random intercepts.

Well, yes, the groups are correlated with one another (especially some groups).
Questions:

What can we do about this? I could regroup some of the industries that are correlated, but this doesn't seem to be a great idea. For example, 'Financials' and 'Industrials' are quite correlated, but these are quite different groups and might have different correlations with other groups.

Is the covariance really an issue? Could be something else as well?



It's an interesting question but for people who are not so familiar with mixed models and how they are related to factor models etc ( I'm one of those people ), it's probably not very clear as far as what's happening. I'm not saying that you weren't clear but more that there's background required.  I'm not sure how you would generate more responses ? Maybe reference the methodology so that people could obtain more details on that part. Also, if you write out the dimensions of the various variables like X, Z, Y that may be useful also.  Are the weekly returns the only factors  in the model ?

The covariance $\mathbf{G}$ is not what causes this issue. The issue persists even in a simple OLS specification, as well as in a fixed-effects specification.
Since both $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ are returns, there is an omitted variable bias. $\mathbf{X}$ are weekly returns of assets in SP500, while $\mathbf{Y}$ are weekly returns of certain portfolios (based on FF formulae and quantile segmentations), again, of assets in the US market (or developed) markets. Hence, it's highly likely that both $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ have some common factors influencing both. If such a factor is omitted, this would lead to a bias estimator and correlated residuals.
This could be formally shown as follows. Suppose the true model is given by:
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + \mathbf{U}\phi + \mathbf{Z}\gamma + \epsilon
$$
Suppose we omit $\mathbf{U}$ and the relationship between $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{X}$
$$
\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{X}\alpha + u
$$
What we will essentially estimate is actually:
$$
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}\beta + (\mathbf{X}\alpha + u)\phi + \mathbf{Z}\gamma + \epsilon \\
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X}(\beta + \alpha\phi) + \mathbf{Z}\gamma + (u\phi+\epsilon)
$$
Hence, if $\phi$ (slope) is non-zero, there is a linear relationship between the residuals and the dependent variable.

that was very nice explanation. what is the reasoning behind using a mixed model versus say the more standard OLS type regression model. Thanks.

It attempts to capture within-group common factors. For example, there might be some common factors that influence the returns of assets only in the Financials industry and some other common factors influencing the Manufacturing industry. The mixed effects model allows us to model these as latent factors.

Thanks deblue. I'll have to look into that but it helps.
